# product of values to ng-model in angularjs template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

```
products = [{"id":null,"classId":1,"multiplier":2,"name":"Deve","units":2},{"id":null,"classId":1,"multiplier":2,"name":"Site","units":2}]
```

I have this JSON object (products) from ajax call. I use ng-repeat and would like to assign the value (product of units and multiplier) to value attribute. I am doing this in my template but value is not assigning. When I inspect value in browser I just see this string ({{(p.units) * (p.multiplier)}}) assigned to value.

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in products>
<td>
<div value="{{(p.unit) * (p.multiplier)}}" fs-counter data-min="0" data-max="10" data-step="{{p.multiplier}}" data-width="75px" data-change="productUnitsChanged(p)">
</td>
</tr>
```

Can anyone suggest me the correct solution to assign product of value (e.g: 4)  to value? I am using angular counter directive - https://github.com/Firestitch/angular-counter

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to use ng-bind?

Comment: Sorry guys I updated my post, I am using fs-angular counter directive and trying to assign its value attribute - github.com/Firestitch/angular-counter

Answer (score 0):

The value attribute of the firestitch directive can't be an expression, meaning it can't be something in double curly braces. It has to be a variable. Something like this will work:

```
<div value="p.multiplier" fs-counter data-min="0" data-max="10" data-step="1" data-width="75px"">
```

but something like this will not work:

```
<div value="{{p.multiplier}}" fs-counter data-min="0" data-max="10" data-step="1"
```